# non-print output in tty in python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I dont know how to properly term what i want.

I want to make a program that doesnt just print and scroll but still be a linux-CLI program.

Lets say i write a program that does 3 things: 
1, its tails a logfile
2, it shows the time
3, it runs a continous ping.

And say i want the time to be displayed in lower right corner, i want the logtail to scroll in the upper 5 lines of the terminal, and i want the ping to scroll (separately) in the main body of the terminal.

So what i am asking, basicly, is: can i make a cli-program behave like a GUI-program where the clock for instance just updates without printing it again, and there are 2 seperate data streams from subprocesses that scroll independantly

Did that make sense? Im pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the Unix terminal more fully with the [`curses` library](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). The library essentially lets you build a simple terminal GUI.

If you need more, take a look at [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) as well. Urwid offers more complex GUI widgets for the discerning terminal GUI developer. :-)