# Python command line interaction library?

Tags: python

I want to develop a small Python app that interacts with the user via the console/command line. Are there any good libraries I can use to get user input and display the output in a nice-looking way? I tried searching but most of what I found was command-line argument processing, didn't see anything about user interaction in the shell.

It should be crossplatform  (Windows and Linux)

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-print output in tty in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603188/non-print-output-in-tty-in-python)

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-pythocli/)
While this uses 'import optparse', they say the current version is 'import argparse' this is not correct. Stick to optparse.
I am also looking at 'import cli' Stay tuned... Flint

Comment: To clarify, @rdodev is **NOT** asking for a CLI library, but a **terminal GUI** library (i.e., curses).  No doubt others will be led here only to find the completely wrong thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the Unix terminal with the [`curses` library](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). The library essentially lets you build a simple terminal GUI.

If you need more, take a look at [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) as well. Urwid offers more complex GUI widgets for the discerning terminal GUI developer. :-)

Comment: urwid looks awesome, will check it out for sure. Hopefully also works in platforms other than unix. If not, I'm thinking a quick-and-dirty Tk UI will cover most platforms.

Comment: @Syrahn: curses is tied to POSIX platforms; there is a wcurses module for Windows, not sure if Urwid will work with that.

Answer (score 12):

A really excellent library is [cmd](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/cmd.html) which is part of the python standard library. It is cross platform Windows, Linux, Mac. You just have to implement one class and it offers so many great features:

1. provides list of supported commands(they end up being implemented as methods)
2. help command that can be called to explain one of your commands
3. handles the whole entering a command, checking syntax, and calling your method command loop cycle.
4. users can save the commands they have run in an interactive session and run them as a script. check out the example below.

If you take the [turtle shell example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/cmd.html#cmd-example) and save it as turtleshell.py and save the below turtle script file as circles.txt

```
circle 20
circle 50
circle 100
bye
```

then you could run the turtle script with the following command:

```
cat circles.txt | ./turtleshell.py
```

so in the simple example shown in the docs the developer has essentially made a simple mini-language that can be used as an easier interface to to the [turtle module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) making it even easier to introduce programming to kids. The examples above have been taken from the python3 docs because they have included a detailed example in their docs which wasn't there in the 2.7 docs, but cmd is available and fully functional in python 2.3 and later.

Answer (score 2):

[Curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) is the most widely used in the Unix environment according to the doc. For Windows you could look at [Windows Console Driver](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm), [WConio](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html) - Windows CONsole I/O for Python or [Wcurses](http://code.google.com/p/wcurses/). I couldn't find much on cross platform console libraries unfortuntaly.

If your Windows users are CLI users they probably have [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which has ncurse support so curses is still the best option if you ask me.

Comment: I saw that, but that leaves Windows users out of the picture. I'm guessing a simple Tk UI would be more cross-platform.

Comment: @Syrahn: Tk doesn't use the console or command line, which you specifically ask about.  Do you actually want a GUI?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I know Tk it's not console. I need a quick UI for user interaction for both Win and Unix. I thought about the shell being quicker, but not worth it if leaves Win users out.